# Retorno incorreto

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Boa noite, estou com um problema na hora de puxar as informações do banco e exibir no show.

[image: A imagem abaixo esta o erro]

meu código está assim:

```
<%= @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object" src="<%= answer.gravatar %>">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading"><%= answer.email %> answered:</h4>
        <%= answer.body %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Valeu galera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O sinal de igual `<%=` serve para validar e printar uma informação, que, neste caso, é o objeto que você está iterando (answer). Tente apenas validar a expressão, alterando de

```
<%= @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
```

para

```
<% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
```